# Login Script with php 5 PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Hi i write the code and when i login i successfully logged in and goto my desire page. But there session is not working. I want to change login Button with the Username but i fail. Please check the where i made mistake.

```
<?php
start_session();
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];
    echo $user_email. $user_pass;
    $sqlQuery= 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email = :user_email';
    $st= $conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
    $st->execute(array('user_email' => $user_email));
    while ($row = $st->fetch()){
        $id =$row['id'];
        $user_pass_hashed = $row['user_pass'];
        $user_name = $row['user_name'];
        if(password_verify($user_pass, $user_pass_hashed)){
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['user_name'];
            header('location: index.php');
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Its Ok');</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Something went wrong');</script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
start_session();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name']))
         echo'<li><a href="login.php" class="btn btn-red">Log In</a></li>';

    else
          echo'<li><a href="admin.php" class="btn btn-red">Logged in</a></li>';
?>
```

Comment: it's session_start()

Comment: `$_SESSION['user_name'];` is doing nothing, you need to assign there.

Comment: your echo under the header will never appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not `start_session` but `session_start()`;

But i am worried as to why this

```
<?php

start_session();
```

did not throw some kind of error?

Change to

```
<?php

    session_start();
```

To prevent php's notice of `session already started`,
do:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
  session_start();//only start if none exists
}
?>
```

EDIT:
Change this

```
if(password_verify($user_pass, $user_pass_hashed)){    
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['user_name'];//this is not set. you need to assign a value
            header('location: index.php');        
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Its Ok');</script>";
        }
```

with:

```
if(password_verify($user_pass, $user_pass_hashed)){    
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;//set current user's name
            header('location: index.php');       
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Its Ok');//header will override this echo.</script>";
        }
```

You need to remove the `echo` line just below the header. It will never be executed. An alternative will be to store the message of success/fail in a session variable and then output it, then unset it

Comment: Thank You for comment.
sorry I made this mistake in this code but in real code i wrote correct.. Please check other code.

Comment: i guess your issue has been fixed?

Comment: Thank You! very much... You're genius 
Now this code work

Comment: the echo here will never happen; header takes over

Answer (score 0):

i think it must be

```
  <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
  session_start(); 
}
?>
```

you set a $_SESSION['user_name'] but you dont provide any data.

> $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
>               $_SESSION['user_name'];

you can check whats inside your session if you just do

```
echo '<pre>;
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>;
```

see [Print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) for more